# What happened to dev member of struct phy_device in linux kernel 4.5 and higher?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

linux kernel 4.4 has had  struct phy_device defined as

```
363 struct phy_device {
364         /* Information about the PHY type */
365         /* And management functions */
366         struct phy_driver *drv;
367 
368         struct mii_bus *bus;
369 
370         struct device dev;
```

and kernel 4.5 has now:

```
361 struct phy_device {
362         struct mdio_device mdio;
363 
364         /* Information about the PHY type */
365         /* And management functions */
366         struct phy_driver *drv;
367 
368         u32 phy_id;
```

what happened to dev member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is replaced with `struct mdio_device;`
The commit message says

> "Not all devices attached to an MDIO bus are phys. So add an
>   mdio_device structure to represent the generic parts of an mdio
>   device, and place this structure into the phy_device."

Look at this [patch](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/patch/include/linux/phy.h?id=e5a03bfd873c29eb786655ef2e95e53ed242b404) which incorporated this change.

Look at changes [only in phy.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/include/linux/phy.h?id=e5a03bfd873c29eb786655ef2e95e53ed242b404) to see how you need to adapt your driver.

Hope this information will guide you to port your driver accordingly.

Comment: Ok, i assume question is answered. Thanks.